# How can I hide div if it is empty?

Tags: jquery

How to hide a div element if it's empty?

**html structure:**

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-5">
         <div class="left-col"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="right-col"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I always know that left-col wont be empty, but right-col might be. If it's empty, I want to hide the whole row.

I tried the following - but no changes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('right-col:empty').hide();
});
```

Comment: Always check console what kind of error it throws. Before posting a question you should check for the solutions first. Dot is missing. Use  $('.right-col:empty')

Comment: @SathishPrabhakaran console wouldn't have thrown an error with the above code.  @PeterPakla There is also another typo in missing the opening `<` on the div

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide the whole row, you should try

```
$('.right-col:empty').parent().parent().hide();
```

or

```
$('.right-col:empty').closest('.row').hide();
```

If you you want to hide only `right-col`, you can do it using only css:

```
.right-col:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `.` in class selector, ie

Change it:

```
$('right-col:empty').hide();
```

to

```
$('.right-col:empty').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using class so use `.`  .

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.right-col:empty').hide();
});
```

```css
.right-col
 {
    background-color: lightblue;
     height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
}
.left-col
 {
    background-color: red;
     height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-5">
         <div class="left-col"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="right-col"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, my div holds <div class="right-col"> </div>, could that be reason why nothing happens?

Comment: nop that is not a problem. If you want to hide col-md-7 you can use parent .  if you want to removes the matched elements from the DOM completely use remove().